# List.Index str instead of int - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

in a project that i'm working on i need to do something like this:

```
import random
lol = ['1c','2c','3c']
k = lol[random.randrange(len(lol))]
lol.pop(lol[lol.index(k)])
print(lol)
```

But I get the error

```
'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I understand where the problem is `lol.index(k)` but still I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Why? Thats the same as `lol.pop(random.randint(0,len(lol)-1))` - you can simply do `lol.pop(lol.index(k))` - see Martjins answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.pop()` takes in index, not a string; you are passing in one of the values from the list.

If you want to produce items in random order, use `random.shuffle()`, then just pop from the end:

```
randomised = lol[:]  # create a copy
random.shuffle(randomised)  # put this in random order

# each time you need a new value
print(randomised.pop())
```

This is much more efficient than picking a random element each time and then removing that element.

Note that instead of using `random.randrange()`, then use that as an index, you could also have used `random.choice()` to pick a single, random value. If `random.shuffle()` does not suit your specific needs, you *should* use:

```
random_index = random.randrange(len(lol))
lol.pop(random_index)
print(lol)
```

Comment: Thanks, understood. Thank you!